# Has anyone encountered Windows installer error 2267: Could not delete storage

Tags: windows-installer

It occurs when trying to install an application.

I could not find information about this error anywhere... Do you know what it means?

Comment: Try creating a verbose log to see what triggers the error: http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log